# Post request with multiple parameters using Android Asynchronous Http Client - James Smith for Android

Tags: android, rest, post

Hi I'm using Android Asynchronous Http Client - James Smith for my Android project and I have a POST request with multiple parameters here's my code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
param.put("name", name);
param.put("last_name", last_name);
param.put("email", email);
param.put("username", username);
param.put("gender", gender);
param.put("mobile", mobile);

client.post("http://*****.herokuapp.com", param, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

and I'm checking the logs from the live server there's a request but the parameters doesn't appear. Can you tell me what is missing for on code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer it should be:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
param.put("name", name);
param.put("last_name", last_name);
param.put("email", email);
param.put("username", username);
RequestParams params = new RequestParams(param);



    client.post("http://***.herokuapp.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  URI uri = new URI("http", "google.com", "/urosecure/upload2.php", "name="+ value + "&time=" + time + "&dated=" + date +       "&devmail="+ possibleEmail + "&gps=" + loc + "&devid=" + deviceid,null);

  String URL = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add or change any thing, just simply add this line:

```
 params.setAutoCloseInputStreams(true);
```

before post the request